# yii2 framework applying a new theme

Tags: themes, yii2

I've gone through the steps in the [guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-theming.md), however my request to index.php gives me "Object not found!"

I have created dirs:

- themes/ directory in /web/
- basic/ directory in /web/themes/
- moved all files from /web/* to /web/themes/basic/
- moved views/ directory to /web/themes/basic/
- have the web.php changed to

  ```
  'components' => [
      'view' => [
          'theme' => [
              'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic/views'],
              'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic/views',
          ]
      ],
  ```

and my AppAsset.php is like

```
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
```

Where I could go wrong?
Also, in cases like this, how can I use debugging?

Answer (score 4):

The guide does not tell you to create the directory @web/themes, it tells you to create @app/themes. So you have created the theme folder in the wrong place. The reason why you should NOT have it in @web is that the entire @web folder is opened to the public, your themes are php files and should not be opened to the public.

@web is basically yourapplicationfolder/web, @app is yourapplicationfolder

In case you use the advanced template yourapplicationfolder is either frontend or backend. Also when I used the theme I configure it like this

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@app/assets/theme/views',
                ],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/',
            ],
        ],
```

Notice that I still have 'baseUrl' => '@web/',

Comment: I have found more information about Yii2 from your answers linked to your profile than I have on the Yii2 Website. This helps a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I need to build my layout/views from html static page templates. What is the best approach to start this activity? I cannot find a good "tutorial".

Comment: just start replacing things with phpcode and yii functions. Tables should be replaced with gridview other things that are repeated you can use ListView, forms should be converted to ActiveForm. It is quite easy.